# AfterTextChanged called even after removing the listener

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have some code in `onItemSelect` which modifies an `EditText` but before doing that I remove its `TextWatcher`. Regardless of that immediately after I modify the `EditText` the `afterTextChanged` method is called. My method is something like this:

```
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
      switch (adapterView.getId()) {
          case R.id.someId:
            // Remove the listener 
            // make changes to the EditText
            // add the listener 

            break;
      }
  }
```

How can I *really* remove the listener? If I don't remove it the thing just calls itself more times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to notify your `TextWatcher` that you are going to modify the text  programmatically. Set this flag (call it `enabled`) before editing the text (instead of removing the listener) and reset it when modification is done. Within your `TextWatcher` you check if this flag is set and if so ignore any changes.

```
class MyTextWatcher extends TextWatcher {

    boolean mIsEnabled = true;

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        mIsEnabled = enabled;
    }

    @Override
    protected afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (!enabled) return;
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```